# Facebook user albums images pagination using latest facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I have to get user albums and entire images within that.what i done so far.

**Step 1 :** Fetch user albums details

```
 Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,picture.type(album),count");
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),  //your fb AccessToken
                "/" + AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId() + "/albums",//user id of login user
                parameters,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(final GraphResponse response) {
         }

        }).executeAsync();
```

**Step 2 :** Fetch images within the albums using album id

```
 Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "images");
        parameters.putString("limit", count);
        /* make the API call */
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/" + albumId + "/photos",
                parameters,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                }

        }).executeAsync();
```

You can see I'm specifying `parameters.putString("limit", count);`
when requesting for albums images and the `count` is the images available in albums.once the count going beyond `100` the response haven't returning all the data.here I came to know something like pagination is needed.how can i do offset based pagination for retrieving all available images in the albums ? can any one help me out.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging // Each API response for endpoints that support pagination returns links to go forward/backward in the response; although I am not sure if you can take that URL and pass it into `GraphRequest` directly, or have to pass in the parameters manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three type of pagination for fetching user photos in facebook ie, Cursor-based Pagination,Time-based Pagination and Offset-based Pagination.In your case you can follow Offset-based Pagination as your asked in query.for that you might need to include an attribute `offset` with `limit` in your graph request.so you can start `offset` by initializing zero then pass the `limit` as `100`.which means you will get records from `0` to `100`.**and note that you can fetch `100` records per request**.for more clearly I'm writing a code sample for fetching album images URL.

```
// ArrayList for storing images URL
private ArrayList<String> albumImages= new ArrayList<>();
// Records offset value, initially zero
private int offset = 0;
// Records count would like to fetch per request
private int limit = 100;

private void getAlbumsImages(final String albumId, final int count, int offsetValue, int limitValue) {
        offset = offsetValue;
        limit = limitValue;
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "images");
        parameters.putString("offset", String.valueOf(offset));
        parameters.putString("limit", String.valueOf(limit));

        /* make the API call */
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/" + albumId + "/photos",
                parameters,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                      /* handle the result */
                        try {
                            if (response.getError() == null) {
                                JSONObject joMain = response.getJSONObject();
                                if (joMain.has("data")) {
                                    JSONArray jaData = joMain.optJSONArray("data");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < jaData.length(); i++)//Get no. of images
                                    {
                                        JSONObject joAlbum = jaData.getJSONObject(i);
                                        JSONArray jaImages = joAlbum.getJSONArray("images");// get images Array in JSONArray format
                                if (jaImages.length() > 0) {
                             albumImages.add(jaImages.getJSONObject(0).getString("source"));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                if (count > offset + limit) {
                                    offset = offset + limit;
                                    if (count - offset >= 100)
                                        limit = 100;
                                    else
                                        limit = count - offset;
                                    getFacebookImages(albumId, count, offset, limit);
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.e("Error :", response.getError().toString());
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
    }
```

You have to make a recursive call to the function to fetch the whole images from the albums or alter the function normally in your RecyclerView scroll.

Usage

```
getFacebookImages(mAlbumsId, mAlbumsImagecount, offset, limit);
```